# Why am I receiving a TypeError for an object type int in python?

Tags: python, testing, arguments, typeerror

So I have a project that I am trying to test to see if it is working as expected. Every time I go to test it it says there is a TypeError or it says I'm not taking enough arguments.

this is an example of a test case I'm using:

```
pirates.process( 0, [( 'Q', 10000 ), ( 'S', 9000), ])
```

my definition looks like this:

```
__init__(people_after_me, items)
```

How do I fix this problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
   yield
File "F:\lib\unittest\case.py", line 605, in run
 testMethod()
File "C:\Users\Travis Jones\PycharmProjects\pirates\piratesTest.py", line 
12, in test00
   ( 'S',  9000 ),
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Post the traceback along with more code, there is not enough information for the rest of us to debug with just that.

Comment: The TypeError occurs when i try and fix this by adding a 3rd argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `__init__` is defined within a class, that becomes a method and it should lead with the [self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) argument for the class instance.

Try defining `__init__` within the class definition like so.

```
    def __init__(self, people_after_me, items):
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo here

`pirates.process( 0, [( 'Q', 10000 ), ( 'S', 9000), ])`

you should close the list and remove the trailing comma

`pirates.process( 0, [( 'Q', 10000 ), ( 'S', 9000 )])`